# Python Library for Stimulating Mouse Position and Keyboard presses

Tags: python-3.6

Please Suggest Python Library to controll Mouse Position While Playing Games Like CS GO . I have Used PynPut ,win32api..,Both not working while playing game

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that this works in the Win32 API is that the input commands are handled with a chain of hooks. Simply speaking the input device sends input to the OS and the OS sends input to the running applications, an application can attach itself to this hook system and choose to suppress the handled input command or pass it along the chain. In the case of some modern games, they take full control of the input chain by not passing the input commands they handle along the chain.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396